# XML parsing in Python for big data

Tags: python, xml, bigdata

I am trying to parse an XML file using Python. But the problem is that the XML file size is around 30GB. So, it's taking hours to execute:

```
tree = ET.parse('Posts.xml')
```

In my XML file, there are millions of child elements of the root. Is there any way to make it faster? I don't need all the children to parse. Even the first 100,000 would be fine. All I need is to set a limit for the depth to parse.

Comment: You'll need to code at a lower level, but you could use a [sax parser](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Sax) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want an XML parsing mechanism that doesn't load everything into memory.

You can use [`ElementTree.iterparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) or you could use [Sax](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Sax).

Here is a page with some [XML processing tutorials](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Tutorials%20on%20XML%20processing%20with%20Python) for Python.

UPDATE: As @marbu said in the comment, if you use `ElementTree.iterparse` be sure to [use it in such a way](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing) that you get rid of elements in memory when you've finished processing them.

Comment: If you decide to go with iterparse, make sure you don't miss this paragraph about [incremental Parsing](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing).