# Preventing memory leak while parsing gigantic XML with etree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

The XML I am trying to parse is pretty large (> 100 GB). I have removed the element in every iteration, also removed the root element. Still, leaking some memory, which becomes considerable (More than 200-300 MB) 
 when the file is pretty large.

The XML structure is like below:

```
<source>
<items>
    <item>
        <id></id>
        <title></title>
        <category></category>
        <city></city>
    </item>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <item>
        <id></id>
        <title></title>
        <category></category>
        <city></city>
    </item>
</items>
</source>
```

My code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import gzip
from lxml import etree
import csv

response = urlopen(url)

response_headers = response.info()
if response_headers.get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip' or 'gzip' in response_headers.get('Content-Type'):
    response = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=response)

context = etree.iterparse(response, events=("start", "end"))
context = iter(context)

_, root = next(context)
_, items_root = next(context)

try:
    for event, item in context:
        if event == "end" and item.tag == "item":
            title = item.find('title').text
            category = item.find('category').text
            city = item.find('city').text
            item.clear()
        items_root.clear()
        root.clear()
except Exception as e:
    raise (e)
```

Previously, I was just clearing `item` and `root`, but later I thought may be `items` are having a lot of empty `item`, which creating memory leaks. But even after adding it, the problem doesn't resolve.

Comment: What does your application actually do with the data? What is the output?

Comment: Are you familar with this [element-iterparse.htm](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm), the `root.clear()` should be inside `if event ...`.

Comment: @MichaelKay, The application saves the derived fields to db/csv, depending on the scenario. Most of the code is removed other than the related parts.

Comment: @stovfl, I have tried both `root.clear()` and `items_root.clear()` inside if, but not with much success. 

Remember, The memory leak is not huge, but it becomes apparent when file is too large.  To be specific when I process > 100 gb file with vm of 1 gb RAM (no time constraint), I face low memory after a centain time.

Comment: I fell that `items_root.clear()` is wrong. Your Questions code shows `root.clear()` **outside** `if event ....`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xml parsing in python for big data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160018/xml-parsing-in-python-for-big-data)